# Natural language interface to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am developing an application in which I need to get result from the database for the user input(natural English text) query.
For starting up I have **tokenized, parsed, NER, POS tagged** the input text (using **Stanford** NLP library).
But what to do next. I mean what practically should I do further so that I can create a proper SQL query from the input text that can de fired on database. How should I process the context of text.

For example I have a database for a company, where I have different tables like employee, department, etc.

 - So when the user types in his query as "*list of employees*", then it should be able to display the list of employees.

 - When user types "*employees from computer department*", then it should display employees with relation to department whose name is computer.

I am using MS-SQL for database (So query needs to be created for SQL from the natural language). And for programming I am using C#.

I have gone through many different documents but all are theoretical. But I didn't find a proper way of implementation.

So any kind of information, data, link, guidance, solution, other way to implement, etc. will be helpful.

Comment: Have you looked into Domain-Specific Languages? This might be a good source of information for you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee943825.aspx

Comment: Depending on how much effort you want to put into this, you could try training a semantic parser for the task (e.g., http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/software/sempre/). You'll need training examples of queries and their associated results, and you'll need some code to run logical forms on your database, but in the end it should work well.

Comment: Hey GD, I am facing the same issue can you tell me how you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite hard question. I doubt it can be answered unambiguously. There can be more than one approach to solve this task. I'm able to tell only about one of them. The simplest one. It's rule-based. A lot of manual mapping work should be done to implement this.

After POS-tagging, a syntax parsing should be done. You should find not only properties of each word but also dependencies between words: links and types of the links between words. Example: `"list of employees"`. Here `"list"` is main, `"employees"` is dependent. The type of the link is `possession`.

Then a semantic analysis should be performed. You have a syntax tree. It should be transformed into an abstract syntax tree (AST).

- Every word or phrase (subtree) should be turned into a semantic node. NER is okay. The node `word: "employees"` becomes `table: EMPLOYEES`. The node `word: "list"` and the node `word: "of"` become kind of `action: SELECT`. You should have an ontology of your domain. Nodes of syntax tree are mapped into nodes of ontology. Mapping is controlled by rules. Sample rule: `if the word is found in the list of tables then replace the node "word: x" with the node "table: x"`. Or another one: `if the word is "list" and a child word is "of" then replace these nodes with "action: SELECT"`.
- Every edge (syntax link) should be turned into a semantic link. Mapping is also controlled by rules. E.g., subtree `table: EMPLOYEES` - `link: POSSESSION` - `entity: ID = 234 ("Computer department") of table DEPARTMENTS` shows that the syntax link `POSSESSION` in this case has meaning `SOURCE` or `FOREIGN KEY`. The sample rule is `table1 - link: POSSESSION - table2` becomes `table1 - where FK_FIELD_OF_TABLE1 = PK_FIELD_OF_TABLE2 - table2` if there exist corresponding foreign key in table1 and primary key of table2.

Your ontology should contain all terms of your domain. Some terms are static (e.g., actions). Some are dynamic and should be queried at runtime while parsing user NL-query (e.g., table names or dictionary tables contents).

Then you construct small queries in SQL at every edge of AST and aggregate results while reaching the top. Sample AST:

```
    action: SELECT
          |
       table: EMPLOYEES
      /                \
where e.DEP_ID = d.ID   where e.SALARY > ?
      |                              |
entity: ID = 234 (DEPARTMENTS)      constant: 435
```

The left edge should be reduced to a constant equality node like the right one. And then a small query `select ID from EMPLOYEES where DEP_ID = 234` is processed. The resulting list is stored at the `table: EMPLOYEES` node.

```
action: SELECT
   |
table: EMPLOYEES (entities: ID in ( 5, 23, 345 ))
   |
where e.SALARY > ?
   |
constant: 435
```

Then the right edge (now it's the only one) is processed for every employee:
`select ID from EMPLOYEES where SALARY > 435 and ID = 5`, `select ID from EMPLOYEES where SALARY > 435 and ID = 23`, `select ID from EMPLOYEES where SALARY > 435 and ID = 345`. The resulting list of IDs is replaced.

Of course, this algorithm can be better. For example, you may wish to combine conditions of all edges of a current node. But it would be difficult to construct one query for the whole tree. So you'd better construct small ones (with simple optimizations probably) and then combine the results.

Also, take a look at the last link I give at the end. There are defined semantically-tractable questions. It's very important to limit the user input. These conditions should be hold:

- The question should contain one of the wh-words (who, where, what etc.) to determine the type of the question (and the type of the answer). This is not obligatory in your case because queries like `list of employees` are permitted.
- Some stop-words are allowed (like `the`, `a`, `an`) and are just ignored.
- All other words should have mappings on ontology nodes.
- Any link between words in a sentence should be interpretable by the system.

If there are any terms that have no mapping then an error should be shown.

Another approach is used at Wolfram|Alpha. [Their FAQ](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/faqs.html) says that their methods "are unlike traditional NLP". I don't know what are those methods. But I would have implemented the system like Wolfram|Alpha by using a plenty of simple syntax patterns. E.g., `who is X` -> `show article X`, `list of X` -> `select * from X`, `with salary more than X` -> `where SALARY > X`.

Also, take a look at controlled languages. The results of NL-queries can be ambiguous and unpredictable. The results of controlled language queries are exact.

More theory:

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_user_interface) about natural language interfaces (to databases also).

One of the most consolidated overview works about NLIDB: Androutsopoulos, I., Ritchie, G. and Thanisch, P. Natural Language Interfaces to Databases - An Introduction.

[Microsoft English Query](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/englishquery.htm): NLIDB implementation from Microsoft.

The definition of semantically-tractable questions is given at this work: Popescu, A-M., Armanasu, A., Etzioni, O., Ko, D., Yates, A. Modern Natural Language Interfaces to Databases: Composing Statistical Parsing with Semantic Tractability.

Comment: More about ontology: it's an extra layer between syntax constructions and tables in DB. User may not know the names of tables. And semantic entities not always correspond to tables. So nodes in ontology should map semantic entities to SQL fragments. E.g., entity `employees` may be not a simple table but a query like `select * from USERS where WORKPLACE = 'OUR_COMPANY'`. Sometimes an additional lexical ontology (with synonyms) is added (WordNet is an example) as a layer before your domain ontology.

Answer (score 0):

Many approaches in the research field of "Natural Language Interfaces to Databases" (NLIDBs) are proposed to answer your question. As mentioned, an overview of this field is presented in the "classical" paper "[Natural language interfaces to databases – an introduction](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S135132490000005X). Natural Language Engineering, 1:29–81, 3 1995." That paper is quite out-of-date, so you might want to look at a recent paper "[Ripple Down Rules for Question Answering](http://www.semantic-web-journal.net/content/ripple-down-rules-question-answering-1), Semantic Web journal, to appear."

Answer (score 0):

My answer is way too late.
But now we have better options like **Microsoft Cognitive Services**, Better NLP Tools, etc.
I am working on chatbot, which has same functionality as yours, where i`ll be using above mentioned tools, with hadoop.

Thanks.